# Labview TCP/IP connection where you use many LEDs

Tags: labview

I have tried to run using TCP/IP, i used type cast and decimal string to number and as well one LED, one numeric. but whenever i run just four LEDs am getting error because i don't know **how many bytes TCP can read**. first its running but whenever i increase the number of LEDs that am sending btw TCP/IP am getting error because first the number of bytes TCP reads i made just 4 bytes. here is my code....
[image]

Comment: Please try and explain more clearly what you're trying to do and what the problem is. Where is the TCP/IP data coming from and what is its format? By 'LEDs' do you mean Boolean values? What error code do you see?

Comment: What is the format of your tcpip stream? At the moment each message is decoded as:
[Lenght{U16?}][Number{2-char ASCII}][Boolean{U8}]